# restrict combobox input zero by user

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to restrict combobox value as '0'  where i have volume value divided by target value as my target value is combobox and gives me an error divide by zero.I tried this but not to luck.

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '0'))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You need input only to be zero? or prevent user from entering zero?

Comment: prevent user from entering zero

Comment: What if user enters `10`? you need to allow or not?

Comment: except 0 in first place every number should be allowed its because anything divide by zero gives me an error.

Comment: Why are you allowing user to type in combo box ? Combo box is used for selecting values from a defined list ? YOu are looking at wrong event. Choose on selected index change event to calculate volumne. You will never put 0 in combo box so you will never get 0 on selected index change

Comment: can you help me with the  code if it was a textbox

Comment: Let me explain it clearly target value changes every day , so the user inputs in runtime and my target should never be zero.

Answer (score 5):

Easy way to go would be handling the `TextChanged` event and reset it back to previous value.
or as suggested in comments don't allow user to enter value just make him to select from a list(DropDownList style).

```
private string previousText = string.Empty;
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == "0")
    {
        comboBox1.Text = previousText;
    }

    previousText = comboBox1.Text;
}
```

I propose this solution since handling *Key Events* is a nightmare, you need to check previous values, Copy + Paste menus, Ctrl+ V shortcuts etc..

Comment: +1 for changing event to _TextChanged_ and using _previousText_ to capture block overwrites (the "!IsNumber" in the _KeyPress_ suggestions in other answers will block the delete key for a start).

Comment: @Nick Not only delete key, backspace, select all and replace with some char etc etc etc there are so many problems to cover with that approach which is gonna screw you somehow later. This will not fail anytime AFAIK :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)
            || (e.KeyChar == '0'
                && this.comboBox1.Text.Length == 0))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do wish to use this event to block the entry of the zeroes then consider the following:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '0')
    {
        if (comboBox1.Text == "")
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (int.Parse(comboBox1.Text) == 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The code could stand a little tidying, but hopefully it shows a simple method of blocking leading zeroes - which I think is what you were after. And, of course, the clauses can all be combined into a single IF once you've got the logic right.